# How to connect IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.2 to Postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, intellij-idea, datasource

I am new to the IntelliJ IDEA IDE world, and would like to connect it to Postgresql as my data source. When I `Test Connection` using my Postgresql database, IntelliJ responds with a `successful` message. [image: Screen shot of Data Sources and Drivers dialog] However, I'm not sure this is all there is to configuring it. As I'm trying to populate my database with with a table and some data. But the table doesn't even appear in the database tool window.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just came back to the sample application and when I tried running it, I got the following error;
`Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE`. After a few searching for it I found that the solution was to place this line in my `application.properties` file `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/<database name>`. and it connected successfully. I didn't need to include a

```
spring.datasource.data-username=<username>
spring.datasource.data-password=<password>
```

but you may have to.

Comment: Did you conflate connecting your database to your IDE with connecting your database to your application?  These are ***very*** different things.

Comment: @Makoto I thought by connecting it in the IDE then it would connect to my application, but I guess I was wrong?

Comment: You were wrong.  Your IDE is not your application, and it never will be.

Answer (score 1):

you are doing it correctly. Once you connect to DB successfully you can press `Apply` and then `Ok`. after that you would see something like in below image in your intelliJ IDE.

[image]

Comment: The thing is that I didn't see any table created in Postgres DB after connecting to it, and running my app, which would insert my table and some fake data, the only reason of my skepticism. Then again i must be doing something wrong in my code.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to settings for your database, make sure you checked `Introspect using JDBC metadata`.

[image]